# How do display a progress spinner in a Dojo FilteringSelect?

Tags: select, dojo, spinner, progress

I have a Dojo FilteringSelect that takes about 20 seconds to load its values from the dB when the user clicks the arrow in the list box.  I'd like to display a progress spinner while waiting for the data to be returned from the dB.  Any ideas what event I would use to show my spinner when  the data is being retrieved from the db and what event to hide the spinner when it completes?  Thanks...

```
new FilteringSelect({
    store: new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ url: "some url here" }),
    autocomplete: true,
    maxHeight: "300",
    required: false,
    id: "country_select_id",
    onChange: function(data) {
        dojo.byId("case_info_status").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
    }
}, "country_select_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet you could go a long way in the select._fetchHandle deferred and the store._fetchItems. Try this

```
var select = new .... Your FilteringSelect Construct( {} );

select._fetchHandle.addCallback(function() {
 // success callback
 dojo.style(dojo.byId('spinner'), "display", "none");

});

dojo.connect(select.store._fetchItems, function() {
   if(select.store._loadFinished) return; // no-op
   dojo.style(dojo.byId('spinner'), "display", "block");
});
```

EDIT:

select._fetchHandle will only be present briefly during the actual download (suppose we can hook onto it after select onOpen called). Instead, another private method in ItemFileReadStore comes in handy

```
dojo.connect(select.store._getItemsFromLoadedData, function() {
     dojo.style(dojo.byId('spinner'), "display", "none");
});
```

Comment: mschr,Thanks for the response and I tried your idea but I keep getting an error message that the "_fetchHandle is undefined".  Any idea how I resolve that?  I'm still trying to figure out this Dojo thing.  Thanks

Comment: ahh sweet, just looked again - the original deferred handler onFetch inside the filteringselect sets the _fetchHandle = null immediately as it starts running..:q

Comment: Pardon my Dojo ignorance, but I take it that means I can't do what I want seeing as the _fetchHandle is set to null?

Comment: there is no real external event in the ItemFileReadStore for queing up function flows on end of a fetch. this is done via store.fetch({cbDeclaration}) - a couple of properties to fetch. The one internal *start* of fetch is `select.store._fetchItems`, use that to display an icon. The other internal *complete* of fetch is `select.store._getItemsFromLoadedData`, use connect on that as with the first to hide an icon